# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un dato desde un controlador de laravel a javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Estoy opteniendo una data de mi base de datos con eloquent de laravel
[image: En la variable users estoy obteniendo la cantidad de personas que fueron registrados al sistema]

y necesito obtener esa información desde un archivo de js que se ubica en la carpta public
[image: En el archibo dashboard.js deseo caputar la información la varia users]

Comment: lo que te recomiendo es que crees un archivo de ruta api en laravel vinculado a tu controlador , y en javascript hagas una peticion ajax, o fetch.

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_, y de ser posible, describí qué contiene la segunda imagen. No todos pueden ver las imágenes: [acá tenés más info](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Leé [ask].